# Haskell - MonadState

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

So I have recently been looking at state monads because I want to build a parser combinator library in haskell.

I came across a typeclass known as MonadState, I was wondering what is the point of this typeclass and  where would you use it?

Comment: `MonadState` is the type class for monads such as `State`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html

Comment: What research have you done to answer this question yourself?  Have you read the documentation?  Have you googled for `MonadState`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MonadState` abstracts out the `get` and `put` functions so that they work not just for one type, but for *any* type that can act as a state monad. It's primarily to make monad transformers work.

Without going into too much detail, let's just assume you know that `StateT` exists: it takes one monad and returns a new monad that can act as state. (I'll ignore the difference between lazy and strict state monads here). A monad that handles state can then be defined by applying `StateT` to the `Identity` monad:

```
newtype State s = StateT s Identity
```

As long as the input type is a monad, we can provide a `MonadState` instance for the monad returned by `StateT`:

```
-- Add state to any monad
instance Monad m => MonadState s (StateT s m) where
    ...
```

This says that applying `StateT` to *any* monad (not just `Identity`) produces a monad that can be treated as a state monad.

Further, you can say that anything that *wraps* a state monad is also a state monad, as long as it implements `MonadState`:

```
-- Add Maybe to a state monad, it's still a state monad
instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (MaybeT m) where
    ...

-- Add Writer to a state monad, it's still a state monad
instance (Monoid w, MonadState s m) => MonadState s (WriterT w m) where
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`MonadState` abstracts the state monad (as if this stuff wasn't abstract enough, right?). Instead of requiring a concrete type `State` with a `Monad` instance, it lets us use any `Monad` we like, provided we can provide appropriate `get` and `put` functions. In particular, we can use `StateT` which lets us combine effects.

simple example combining State and IO:

```
tick :: (MonadIO m, MonadState Int m) => m ()
tick = do
  x <- get
  liftIO $ putStrLn ("incrementing " ++ (show x))
  put (x+1)

> runStateT (tick >> tick >> tick >> tick) 5
incrementing 5
incrementing 6
incrementing 7
incrementing 8
((),9)
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, using a concrete type with `MonadState` in the signature requires enabling the `FlexibleInstances`.